# Ошибка при делении целых чисел

Tags: c

Есть код:

```
//buf.st_size типа off_t и равен 2147583648
//countProcess типа int и равен 4
//len типа unsigned long long
len =  buf.st_size / countProcess;
printf("len: %llu\n", len);
```

В результате деления должно получиться 536895912, но вместо этого получается какой то мусор. Если же вместо buf.st_size подставить 2147583648 то все делится нормально. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Элементарно, Ватсон.

Ваше значение не вписывается в *32-битное знаковое число*, только и всего... А когда вы его указываете явно - оно принимается как вполне помещающееся беззнаковое значение, и нормально делится.

Если вы запишете деление как

```
unsigned long long len =  (unsigned long)st_size / countProcess;
```

у вас все получится...

У вас число превращается в отрицательное значение типа `long`, делится, получается отрицательное же значение, которое потом, при превращении в `unsigned long long` расширяется знаково на все 64 бита, а потом это число рассматривается как беззнаковое. Вот как это выглядит в шестнадцатеричной записи:

`800186A0` после знакового деления на 4 превращается в `E00061A8`, а после знакового расширения до 64 бит - в `FFFFFFFFE00061A8`.

Comment: Вот так и знал, что ошибка глупая... Все понял, все работает. Спасибо большое)